# How to search an "ADD" if the object has been deleted

Tags: hibernate-envers

I am trying to look up an object in my envers table, but I dont have the PK. Instead of the PK I have a field ("child") . This is my query,

> List resultList = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(TP.class, false, true)
>   .add(AuditEntity.property("child").eq(nodeid)).getResultList();

But I get this:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [id] not found on java.lang.Long

Or are there any chance of searching by custom fields for revisions?

Regards, Johann

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `child` is a relation, than you need to use `AuditEntity.relatedId("child").eq(nodeid)`. See also [15.7.1 in the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-queries)

Comment: you cant append an string "_id"  and it works as well